# Can't access the IBOutlets of my custom cell on cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I made a custom cell with a XIB:
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TWCustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    IBOutlet UILabel *nick;
    IBOutlet UITextView *tweetText;
}

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TWCustomCell.h"

@implementation TWCustomCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

And I load them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    TWCustomCell *cell = (TWCustomCell*)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObject = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TWCustomCell" owner:nil options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObject) {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                cell = (TWCustomCell*) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.tweetText.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

On `cell.tweetText.text = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`
On the dot after `cell`, Xcode tells me_ "Property 'tweetText' not found on object of type 'TWCustomCell *'; did you mean to access ivar 'tweetText'?" and tells me to replace it with
`cell->tweetText.text`. But there appears the error: "Semantic Issue: Instance variable 'tweetText' is protected". What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with my custom cell ivars:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TWCustomCell : UITableViewCell {
    //added here @public and you can access them now
    @public
    IBOutlet UILabel *nick;
    IBOutlet UITextView *tweetText;
}

@end
```

Comment: You can declare them as @property

Comment: Messing with another object's instance variables is ugly and janky. Declaring them with `@public` is a band-aid to enable something that is disabled by default for a good reason. You really should declare (`@property`) and use (`.`, not `->` — i.e., the expressions you started with) properties instead.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't declare a property that will allow access to the IBOutlets outside of the class with the dot syntax.

Here's how i would do it:

in your .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *nick;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) UITextView *tweetText;
```

in the .m:

```
@synthesize nick, tweetText;
```

Or you could remove the ivar IBOutlets and declare the properties as retain and IBOutlets like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *nick;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *tweetText;
```

Comment: I get the error: "Semantic Issue: Instance variable 'tweetText' is protected" again when doing that, but not when using `@public`

Comment: @zad0xsis you should use "." instead of "->" and it will work. using properties is the convention, accessing public ivars (with "->") is against the conventions